# :Last-Child not working with Nav Bar?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="header"><!--start #header-->
    <img id="logo" height="80" src="../resources/CHUG-LOGO.png" />
    <ul>
        <a href="../home" title="Home"><li id="home"><h2>Home</h2></li></a>
        <a href="../about" title="About"><li id="about"><h2>About</h2></li></a>
        <a href="../store" title="Store"><li id="store"><h2>Store</h2></li></a>
        <a href="../contact" title="Contact"><li id="contact"><h2>Contact</h2></li></a>
    </ul>                    
</div><!--end #header-->
```

```css
#header ul {
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
}
#header ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 65px;
    border-left: 1px solid #755b2c;
    border-right: 1px solid #b99e68;
}
#header ul li h2 {
    min-width: 105px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is the code I have for my nav bar, and I am trying to remove the right border on the last list item.  I know I need to use the psuedo identifier :last-child, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: You really shouldn't wrap the LI in an A tag. LI *should* be the direct child of the UL element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li`s are technically not children of the `ul` element since they are wrapped by `a` elements. Move the `a` to the inside of the `li` and use the same code again.

Comment: If I move the 'a' to the inside of the 'li' then you have to click only the text for the link to work. I want the entire list item to be the link not just the text.

Comment: That's good to know though thank you, but is there anyway to make the entire LI still be the linK?

Comment: Make the `<a>` `display: block`

Comment: Add `display:block` to the CSS for the `a` elements and set their height and width to `100%`.

Comment: Actually, you would have to remove the padding on the `li`s and add them to the `a`s. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#header ul a:last-child li {
  border-right: none
}
```

but don't forget that last:child doesn't work in IE6, IE7 and IE8:
http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html